# Posting poll to wall

Tags: facebook-wall

Hope you can help.
I've got the file to post to my wall.

```
$facebook->api("/$pageid/feed", "post", array(
message => "$msg",
access_token => $access_token));
```

Which works perfectly.
Is it possible to post a poll including various options?

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Question object: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question/

Question option object: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question_option/

The permission is `user_questions`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions

The connection is on the user object: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user

To see a list of questions a user has asked:  https://graph.facebook.com/me/questions

However, there is no way via the API to post a new question.  Sorry.